# Data fetched from server not loading into redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm fetching data from a mongoDB database and then fetch that data from the server and finally render the data to the UI in a specified component. I'm using redux-toolkit for state management.
The problem is when fetching the data from the server it is not visible in the store. Why is the empty array in the initial state still empty after fetching the data? I'm using createSlice Api that generates the action creators and action types and createAsyncThunk Api for the asynchronous task of fetching the data from the server.

Slice reducer

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import axios from 'axios'

const initialState = {
    realestate: [],
    isSuccess: false,
    isLoading: false,
    message: '',
}

export const getRealEstates = createAsyncThunk(
    'realestate/getRealEstates', async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get('castles')
            return response.data
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
)


export const estateSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'realestate',    
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        reset: (state) => initialState,
    },
    extrareducers: (builder) => {
        
        builder.addCase(getRealEstates.pending, (state) => {
            state.isLoading = true
        })
        builder.addCase(getRealEstates.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.isLoading = false
            state.isSuccess = true
            state.realestate = action.payload
        })
         builder.addCase(getRealEstates.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.isLoading = false
            state.isError = true
            state.message = action.payload
        })
    }
})

export const { reset } = estateSlice.actions
export default estateSlice.reducer
```

Store

```
export const store = configureStore({
reducer: {
    realestate: realestateReducer,
    registered: registerReducer,
  },
});
```

Component

```
const realestates = useSelector(state => state.realestate)
const { isLoading, realestate, isError, message, isSuccess} = realestates

const dispatch = useDispatch()

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getRealEstates())
        if(realestate){
            setShow(true)
        }else{
            console.log('No data retrieved')
        }
    
}, [dispatch, isError, realestate, message])
```

Comment: Have you checked if the action `getRealEstates.fulfilled` is getting dispatched and if the respective reducer case is entered? (debugger)

Comment: @timotgl Redux devTools is showing me that the action is fulfilled but the case is not entered, thus not showing in the store. The empty array is still empty.

Comment: Btw with typescript you can avoid these kinds of errors, there'd be a compiler checking if `createSlice` receives known arguments. Not saying you need to migrate, but it's an option (with other drawbacks of course).

Comment: I sure will consider that. Typos like that can be time consuming and frustrating.       Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `extraReducers` with an uppercase `R`, your code contains `extrareducers`.

Comment: I can't believe this, thank you so much. You saved my day!!